# How to access document in firestore

Tags: angular, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, angularfire2

I have a firebase database with a `users` node on the top. For example I want to get the first child of that node. I am trying to access in this way, but i says that:

`TypeError: "this.users[0] is undefined"`

```
export class FirebaseService {
  user: Observable<User | null>
  userCollection: AngularFirestoreCollection<User>;
  users: Observable<User[]>;

  getUserByEmail(email) {
     this.userCollection = this.afs.collection('users');
     this.users = this.userCollection.valueChanges();
     let a = this.users[0].name;
```

I have looked at a lot of tutorials already but I could not find the reason for the error I am getting

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Need to subscribe to the `valueChanges`

```
this.userCollection.valueChanges().subscribe((item) => {
   this.users = item;
   console.log(this.users[0].name)
})
```

Comment: `Type 'User[]' is not assignable to type 'Observable<User[]>'.
  Property '_isScalar' is missing in type 'User[]'.`

Comment: change  the type of user `users: User[];`

Comment: Make sure to check answer if this helped.

Comment: yes i was just waiting for the time limit constraint